# running multiple sudo'd commands concurrently

Tags: zsh, sudo

I've once again been bitten by out-of-date caches. I finally got tired of looking up all the cache rebuilding commands and decided to write myself a short zsh function to do all the ones I know about (and as I discover more they can go in here). Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
recache() {
    sudo true
    sudo updatedb &
    local updatedbpid=$!
    sudo ldconfig &
    local ldconfigpid=$!
    rehash
    wait $updatedbpid $ldconfigpid
}
```

The first `sudo true` is intended to make sure `sudo` has a recent timestamp, so that the following background processes don't sit suspended on input waiting for me to type my password. I don't use `sudo -b` because I want to `wait` until the caches are up to date before continuing my work.

Most of the time, this works great; but about one time in three or so, I get endless copies of the following text:

```
[2]  + suspended (tty output)  sudo updatedb
```

Why? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I never did figure out why this was happening. My best guess is there's some resource that `sudo` is trying to lock, and the two invocations of `sudo` get in a race for it. In any case, I've been using the following modified `recache` function for some time without trouble. The main difference is that there is only a single backgrounded `sudo`, and it runs both `updatedb` and `ldconfig` in parallel, rather than one backgrounded `sudo` per process.

```
recache() {
    sudo true
    sudo zsh -c 'updatedb & ldconfig & wait' &
    local pid=$!
    rehash
    wait $pid
}
```